# Tabulator Horizontal scrollbar using fitDataStretch together with Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, tabulator

I'm using the most recent version of Tabulator (6.0.1) and tbe latest version of Bootstrap (5.3.3). When I setup my table with the layout:fitDataStretch option, a horizontal scrollbar is showing up at the bottom of the table. This scrollbar is rather useless, because if I use the mouse to make a random column just 1 pixel smaller, the scrollbar disappears again.

I tried reverting back to Bootstrap 4 and that resolved the problem. However, I do want to use Bootstrap 5 for it's new capabilities

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.